# Rep League's badge tooltip count is wrong

Tags: bug, status-completed, reputation-leagues

It always shows that every user in any site has 3 gold badges, 35 silver badges and 59 bronze badges.

http://www.imgftw.net/img/776958273.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed.  Nice catch.

Comment: Thanks. BTW, it should show "1 gold badge" instead of "1 gold badges".